# Indian passport validity, returning to US with valid Green Card

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passports

I am travelling to India on Dec 4, 2019 with an Indian passport that is valid until April 04, 2020.

I shall be returning to the United States on Jan 13 with a   valid Green Card.

Will there be any issue in my travel or is my passport good?

Comment: Where do you leave from?

Answer (score 3):

A valid Indian passport, of any length of validity, should be sufficient to enter and leave India.

From the US point of view, a returning permanent resident with a valid green card *does not even need a passport* to re-enter at all, so it is obviously not a problem to have a valid passport of any length of validity. See [this answer](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1191?language=en_US) from the CBP:

> United States (U.S.) LPRs do not need a passport to enter the U.S.

And the CBP [carrier information guide](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2019-Mar/2019%20Carrier%20Information%20Guide%20-%20ENGLISH.pdf) (see page 28):

> A Lawful Permanent Resident may travel to the United States without a
>   passport with a Permanent Resident Card (Form I-551).

Answer (score 1):

For an Indian national, with a valid US Green Card, the passport must be valid upon the last stage of travel (i.e. leaving India and entering the United States).

A minimal validity of the passport is not required in this case, since the US will assume that you will apply for a new passport after your return (here the Green Card is important).

---

As a general rule most countries **require** that a passport be valid upon the expected exit (US), often plus 3 months (Schengen Area).

So when planning an extensive travel during the **last 6 months** of your passport validity, applying for a new passport is **advised** to avoid problems caused by any unexpected delays.

---

> **What documents do I need to present to reenter the United States?**
>   If seeking to enter the United States after temporary travel abroad, **you will need to present a valid, unexpired “Green Card” (Form I-551, Permanent Resident Card)**. When arriving at a port of entry, a U.S. Customs and Border Protection Officer will review your permanent resident card and any other identity documents you present, such as a passport, foreign national I.D. card or U.S. Driver’s License, and determine if you can enter the United States.  For information pertaining to entry into the United States, see U.S. Customs and Border Protection’s webpage.

---

> **Indian Passengers**
>   Indian nationals travelling abroad require a valid Indian passport and travel authority for the destination country. nationals travelling abroad require **a valid Indian passport** and travel authority for the destination country.

---

**Sources**:

- [International Travel as a Permanent Resident | USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-a-permanent-resident)
- [Indian Passengers](https://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers)

Comment: "since the US will assume that you will apply for a new passport after your return" No, the US does not assume that, and a green card holder is not required to have a valid passport.

Comment: A US LPR does not need a passport to enter the US nor to remain in the US.  The US actually requires the passport to be valid for *six* months beyond the date of departure in the general case, but there is a list of exceptions where the passport does not need any extra validity.  Oddly, the list of exceptions comprises more than half of the world's countries.

Comment: When traveling from India the passport **must** be valid. On entering the US they won't care about the minimum validity of the passport for Green Card holders as they would for others. Please read it in the context of the question.@user102008, phoog